# Laravel Validator not working - Could this be a bug in Laravel 6 Validator

Tags: laravel

I think there is a bug in Laravel 6 validator

Kindly help me make sense of this:
I wish to validate a certain `unid`, see my rules below

Test1

```
    $validator = validator(['unid' => '4444'], [
            'unid' => 'required|digits:16|unique:users,unid',
     ]);

    //This works, says `unid must be 16 digits
```

Test2 - passed in an array

```
    $validator = validator(['unid' => [2232323232]], [
            'unid' => 'required|digits:16|unique:users,unid',
     ]);

    //I expected the validator `digits:16` to fail here since an array was passed but it throws an error
    //local.ERROR: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to
    //be string, array given {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): 
    //preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given at ...
```

Here is a scenario to help you understand.
Assuming this is an API and a malicious user post an array instead of string or numbers $request->unid === [2232323232, 22222], your application throws error 500.

Kindly help me investigate this issue

Comment: It looks like both rules are working fine. By using `digits:16`, Laravel automatically forces the data type to be numeric, which an array isn't.

Answer (score 0):

add below code after $validator

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
   return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

Comment: This not about displaying errors, its about validator issue, you start by testing this code on your dev env. `$validator = validator(['unid' => [2232323232], [
            'unid' => 'required|digits:16',
     ]);
`

Comment: see example in test Test2 - passed in an array, should'nt that validate  to false since I passed in an array  and its expecting a digit ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays -   please see

Comment: You didn't get my point. My code is correct. Assuming this is an API and a malicious user post an array instead of string or numbers $request->unid === [2232323232, 22222]

Comment: ok , i understand !  don't worry    beacause after send  [2232323232, 22222]  convert to '[2232323232, 22222]' String !!!! and not problem with validation

Comment: So you agree this a problem right ? because we don't need conversion to string during validation

Comment: yes but user cann't  send array to validator !!!
laravel automacally convert to string

Comment: have you tested this $validator = validator(['unid' => [2232323232]], [
            'unid' => 'required|digits:16',
     ]); because I don't think you get the point , `digits:16` is not working in this case

Comment: yes i tested !!! your code has problem beacause user cann't send [2323232] ,
best test is better with input or send [232323,22222] and understand you cann't send [1232323] value

Comment: who said you can't post an array ? I tested with API. I understand how validation works. This is  bug

Comment: i tested laravel api and send [123,33,223] and then convert to  string of '[123,33,223]'

Comment: I don't want to convert to string